# How to search in a pandas dataframe column with the space in the column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I need to search if a  value exists in a pandas data frame column , which has got a name without any spaces, then I simply do something like this

> `if value in df.Timestamp.values`

This will work if the column name is Timestamp. However, I have got plenty of data with column names as 'Date Time'. How do I use the if in statement in that case?
If there is no easy way to check for this using the if in statement, can I search for the existence of the value in some other way? Note that I just need to search for the existence of the value. Also, this is not an index column.

Thank you for any inputs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better practice to use the square bracket notation:

```
df["Date Time"].values
```

Which does exactly the same thing

Comment: thank you for your prompt answer. I didn't realise that one can use square brackets in this context.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of indexing columns in pandas. One is using the dot notation which you are using and the other is using square brackets. Both work the same way.

```
if value in df["Date Time"].values
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Both the answers that are provided are correct and I had to choose one.. Thank you for explaining the terms of dot notation and square brackets

Answer (score 1):

> in the case where you want to work with a column that has a header name with spaces
>   but you don't want it changed because you may have to forward the file 
>   ...one way is to just rename it, do whatever you want with the new no-spaced-name, them rename it back...# e.g. to drop the rows with the value "DUMMY" in the column 'Recipient Fullname'

```
df.rename(columns={'Recipient Fullname':'Recipient_Fullname'}, inplace=True) 
df = df[(df.Recipient_Fullname != "DUMMY")]   
df.rename(columns={'Recipient_Fullname':'Recipient Fullname'}, inplace=True)
```